# Java -> Crypt32Util -> Incorrect parameter

Tags: java, windows, encryption

For a school project I need to retrieve encrypted data from Windows crypt function.
I'm using Java 17, Gradle with the latest dependency for the Crypt32Util class :

```
"implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.12.1'"
```

I retrieve my data using ResultSet from SQLite database, the data is stored in byte array :

```
byte[] data = rs.getBytes(6);
```

Then, using the Crypt32Util built-in method cryptUnprotectData :

```
Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(data);
```

This give me the following error :

> com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Paramètre incorrect.

Basically, it's written that I put an incorrect parameter, the only thing asked is a byte array, but the method :

```
Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(byte_array);
```

is calling / equal to :

```
Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(data, null, 0, null);
```

I wonder is there something wrong with the lib, or even with my OS since i'm using Windows 11

---

**Reproductible example :**

Byte array :  [118, 49, 48, 97, 69, -91, 123, 16, -86, -29, -49, 63, 83, 84, 80, 69, 64, -53, -83, -120, -97, -91, 111, 82, -114, 104, 119, 41, 89, -55, -64, 48, -56, 65, -33, -2, 40, 76, 104]

Code using the Crypt32Util method :

```
byte[] dataBytes = rs.getBytes(6);
byte[] dataBytes2 = {118, 49, 48, 97, 69, -91, 123, 16, -86, -29, -49, 63, 83, 84, 80, 69, 64, -53, -83, -120, -97, -91, 111, 82, -114, 104, 119, 41, 89, -55, -64, 48, -56, 65, -33, -2, 40, 76, 104};
Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(dataBytes2); // <-- ERROR HERE
```

This byte array should in fact return "password"

Comment: *win32* You have a 32 library on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: From what I've searched there's no win64 / Crypt64Util so yes, I don't really think it's related to that

Comment: Ok You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would try to go with last version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna

Comment: Still the same problem with latest version

Comment: I also added a reproducible example and modified the graddle JNA-PLATFORM implementation

Comment: I do not think this is related to 32/64 bit architecture. Have you tried with flag `CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN`